# Run android service via remote command

Tags: java, android

I have the following code that runs in a service where it captures screenshots from Android. What technology could I use to send a remote command to this service to execute the task? I don't want it to run from a MainActivity button. Firebase cloud messaging ? Websocket ?

ScreenCaptureService.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.util.Pair;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ScreenCaptureService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "ScreenCaptureService";
    private static final String RESULT_CODE = "RESULT_CODE";
    private static final String DATA = "DATA";
    private static final String ACTION = "ACTION";
    private static final String START = "START";
    private static final String STOP = "STOP";
    private static final String SCREENCAP_NAME = "screencap";

    private static int IMAGES_PRODUCED;

    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private String mStoreDir;
    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Display mDisplay;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private int mDensity;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private int mRotation;
    private OrientationChangeCallback mOrientationChangeCallback;

    public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScreenCaptureService.class);
        intent.putExtra(ACTION, START);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT_CODE, resultCode);
        intent.putExtra(DATA, data);

        return intent;
    }

    public static Intent getStopIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScreenCaptureService.class);
        intent.putExtra(ACTION, STOP);
        return intent;
    }

    private static boolean isStartCommand(Intent intent) {
        return intent.hasExtra(RESULT_CODE) && intent.hasExtra(DATA)
                && intent.hasExtra(ACTION) && Objects.equals(intent.getStringExtra(ACTION), START);
    }

    private static boolean isStopCommand(Intent intent) {
        return intent.hasExtra(ACTION) && Objects.equals(intent.getStringExtra(ACTION), STOP);
    }

    private static int getVirtualDisplayFlags() {
        return DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
    }

    private class ImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try (Image image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage()) {
                if (image != null) {
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

                    // create bitmap
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                    // write bitmap to a file
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(mStoreDir + "/myscreen_" + IMAGES_PRODUCED + ".png");
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                    IMAGES_PRODUCED++;
                    Log.e(TAG, "captured image: " + IMAGES_PRODUCED);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private class OrientationChangeCallback extends OrientationEventListener {

        OrientationChangeCallback(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            final int rotation = mDisplay.getRotation();
            if (rotation != mRotation) {
                mRotation = rotation;
                try {
                    // clean up
                    if (mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                    if (mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);

                    // re-create virtual display depending on device width / height
                    createVirtualDisplay();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private class MediaProjectionStopCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.e(TAG, "stopping projection.");
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                    if (mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                    if (mOrientationChangeCallback != null) mOrientationChangeCallback.disable();
                    mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(MediaProjectionStopCallback.this);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // create store dir
        File externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        if (externalFilesDir != null) {
            mStoreDir = externalFilesDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshots/";
            File storeDirectory = new File(mStoreDir);
            if (!storeDirectory.exists()) {
                boolean success = storeDirectory.mkdirs();
                if (!success) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory.");
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory, getExternalFilesDir is null.");
            stopSelf();
        }

        // start capture handling thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                mHandler = new Handler();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (isStartCommand(intent)) {
            // create notification
            Pair<Integer, Notification> notification = NotificationUtils.getNotification(this);
            startForeground(notification.first, notification.second);
            // start projection
            int resultCode = intent.getIntExtra(RESULT_CODE, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            Intent data = intent.getParcelableExtra(DATA);
            startProjection(resultCode, data);
        } else if (isStopCommand(intent)) {
            stopProjection();
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startProjection(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        MediaProjectionManager mpManager =
                (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        if (mMediaProjection == null) {
            mMediaProjection = mpManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
            if (mMediaProjection != null) {
                // display metrics
                mDensity = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
                WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                mDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

                // create virtual display depending on device width / height
                createVirtualDisplay();

                // register orientation change callback
                mOrientationChangeCallback = new OrientationChangeCallback(this);
                if (mOrientationChangeCallback.canDetectOrientation()) {
                    mOrientationChangeCallback.enable();
                }

                // register media projection stop callback
                mMediaProjection.registerCallback(new MediaProjectionStopCallback(), mHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopProjection() {
        if (mHandler != null) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mMediaProjection != null) {
                        mMediaProjection.stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private void createVirtualDisplay() {
        // get width and height
        mWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        mHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        // start capture reader
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, mWidth, mHeight,
                mDensity, getVirtualDisplayFlags(), mImageReader.getSurface(), null, mHandler);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(), mHandler);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Date;

import app.mobile.secure.appservice.api.AppUtil;
import app.mobile.secure.appservice.configuracao.Permissao;
import app.mobile.secure.appservice.service.MonitorService;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
  

    private MediaProjectionManager projectionManager;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
       
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
            startActivityForResult(projectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
        }   
       
    }
   

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                startService(app.mobile.secure.appservice.service.ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent(this, resultCode, data));

                startProjection();
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startProjection() {
        MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager =
                (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
    }

   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using firebase Messaging in conjunction with your backend.

You can read about it here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?authuser=0#implementation_paths

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?authuser=0

Comment: Thanks, I will study the documentation, this solution will help me.